# Web audio : when mobile screen turns off, setTimeout slows down

Tags: javascript, android, browser, settimeout, web-audio-api

EDIT: per Yogi's comment (see "setTimeout" and "throttling" in  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout ), I've tried adding an AudioContext to prevent the slowdown.

```
document.addEventListener('click', ev => {
    let audCtxt = new AudioContext({});
});
```

(AudioContext needs user interaction, hence the event listener.)

But, no luck.

Other ideas I'm noting here to follow up are

- maybe a `while` loop, checking `Date.now()` for multiples of 10ms -- but I think that would crash the page
- maybe using `requestAnimationFrame`?

---

Original post:

I have a `setTimeout` firing every 0.01 seconds that's acting as a master clock for my web app.

The app plays synchronized sounds that respond to user interaction, hence the need for a master clock.  Simplified:

```
let counter = 0;
setTimeout(() => {
    counter++;
    console.log(counter);
}, 10);
```

When on a mobile device, **the setTimeout slows down (about 2-4x) when the screen is locked/off.**  (Tested on Android, not iOS).

This can be verified by logging, like the above, or by generating a sound when the counter is multiple of 100.

1. How can I prevent this?
2. Should I be taking a different approach to a "master clock" that synchronizes triggering audio samples while still allowing the audio to respond in real time to user interaction?

Comment: Since this happens during screen lock perhaps it's a result of automatically timer throttling.  Yet, that would depend on the device and what else the app is doing.  See "Timeouts in inactive tabs" and "Throttling of tracking scripts" sections of [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout).

Comment: @Yogi - interesting > It may also be waived if a page is playing sound using a Web Audio API AudioContext.  Thanks for the docs pointer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` is not reliable as other things, such as promises, have higher execution priority. One possible workaround is to create a custom timer using promises. Here is an example:

```
var customDelay = new Promise(function (resolve) {
    var delay = 10; // milliseconds
    var before = Date.now();
    while (Date.now() < before + delay) { };
    resolve();
});

customDelay.then(function () {
    //Timer triggered
});
```

**Update 1:**

Given that you want a 10ms update frequency, running the above code on the main thread ends up locking up the UI due to the while loop. With that in mind, offloading that while loop into a web worker would resolve this. Here is some code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script id="FastTimer" type="javascript/worker">
        onmessage = function (event) {
            var delay = 10; // milliseconds
            var before = Date.now();
            while (Date.now() < before + delay) { };
            postMessage({data: []});
        };
    </script>
    
  <script>
    var worker;
  
    window.onload = function() {
      var blob = new Blob([document.querySelector("#FastTimer").textContent]);
      blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

      worker = new Worker(blobURL);
      
      worker.addEventListener("message", receivedWorkerMessage);
      worker.onerror = workerError;

      //Start the worker.
      worker.postMessage({});
    }

    var counter = 0;
    
    function receivedWorkerMessage(event) {
        worker.postMessage({});
        timerTiggered();
    }

    function timerTiggered() {
        counter++;
        console.log(counter);
    }

    function workerError(error) {
      alert(error.message);
    }

    function stopWorker() {
      worker.terminate();
      worker = null;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The main issue with the above is that I suspect there would be some sort of time cost going back and forth between the worker (maybe a couple ms, hard to say).

As mentioned, normally `requestAnimationFrame` is used for animations in web apps. However, this would likely not fire when the screen is locked. But if you want to try, here is a sample:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    var counter = 0;
    var minTimeSpan = 10;
    var lastTime = performance.now();
    
    function animate() {
        let t = performance.now();

        if (t - lastTime >= minTimeSpan) {
            timerTiggered();
        }
    
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
    
    function timerTiggered() {
        counter++;
        console.log(counter);
    }
    
    animate();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice idea -- just tried this -- unfortunately, it made the page unresponsive, and sometimes crashed the browser tab.  But I feel like the `Date.now()` strategy might be on to something, so I'm going to explore that.

Comment: I originally had tested with 100 ms instead of 10ms. Having anything fire at 10ms constantly is a bit crazy for a web app. Usually `requestAnimationFrame` would be the way to go for anything related to animations, however, that only works when the page is in view (i.e. if screen locked or you go to another tab, it doesn't fire).

Comment: Hmm, for audio alignment, 0.01 is roughly the minimum viable precision.  I tried checking Date.now() in a while() loop, but that froze the page, too.

Comment: This is excellent, and it remains interactive, so it can be stopped by user actions!  I need to do a bit more testing, but I'm hopeful that this will be a simple and concise way to solve the problem.  Kudos!

Comment: Refactored my app to use web workers based on your answer -- still totally interactive, and the screen-off slowdown has *mostly* gone away!   (Now the slowdown is 10% instead of 200%, but there's a bit of a "wobble" to the timing now.) Thanks for taking the time to explore this -- I learned something!  The next mystery is to investigate the 10% and the wobble... :)

Answer (score 1):

This can usually be solved by using a Web Worker for running the timer. I created a library which looks like `setTimeout()` but uses a Web Worker internally.

https://github.com/chrisguttandin/worker-timers

But there was a bug a while ago in some browser (I forgot which one it was) which caused this to not work any longer. Therefore I built the same abstraction on top of a running `AudioContext`.

https://github.com/chrisguttandin/audio-context-timers

But as you already said this only works if the page is already allowed to run an `AudioContext` by starting one in response to a click handler.

Comment: Ah!  Looking forward to trying this.  Can the user interact with the timer while it's running?

Comment: This is indeed the problem I was trying to solve, but I'm failing to even load the modules... I've created a separate SO question about my attempt.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72553673/client-side-import-map-unable-to-locate-module-error-404