# Client-side import map unable to locate module (error 404)

Tags: javascript, html, browser, es6-modules, import-maps

I'm attempting to import a module in vanilla JS in the browser (no bundler).

The module is worker-timers (https://github.com/chrisguttandin/worker-timers), which I installed into the same directory as my `index.html` via `npm install`.

But I get multiple 404 errors, like `GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/node_modules/worker-timers/build/es2019/factories/load-worker-timers net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

My minimal code is below.

```
<body>
    <script type="importmap">
{ "imports": {
  "worker-timers":        "./node_modules/worker-timers/build/es2019/module.js",
  "worker-timers-broker": "./node_modules/worker-timers-broker/build/es2019/module.js",
  "worker-timers-worker": "./node_modules/worker-timers-worker/build/es2019/module.js"
} }
</script>
    <script type="module">
        import * as workerTimers from 'worker-timers';
        console.log(workerTimers);
    </script>
</body>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Or, I'm happy to import them any way that works, if there's an alternative.

Comment: I think the error tells you that the `node_modules` folder is not exposed by your server. Anyway, worker-timers can't be used directly in the browser as of now. But you can use a service like JSPM if you want to avoid a bundler. The following should work: `<script type="module">import workerTimers from 'https://dev.jspm.io/npm:worker-timers';</script>`

Answer (score 0):

As Chris pointed out, node_modules is not directly accessible from the browser. If you're using express, you could do something like:

```js
app.use('/mat', express.static('./node_modules/@material/web'));
```

The problem is then the dependencies wouldn't be resolved. If you do that, you may receive an error for `tslib` that is missing, so in turn you have to expose all the libraries in node_modules. Better to stick it with Rollup or something like that